# How to use Dozer with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, dto, dozer

I am working on a Spring Boot project. I just have annotation configuration. I want to include dozer to transform Entities to DTO and DTO to Entities. I see in the dozer website, they explain i have to add the following configuration in spring xml configuration file. Since i have not xml file but annotation configuration Java class, i don't know how to translate this into Java Configuration class.

```
<bean id="org.dozer.Mapper" class="org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper">
  <property name="mappingFiles">
    <list>
      <value>dozer-global-configuration.xml</value>
      <value>dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
      <value>more-dozer-bean-mappings.xml</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

If someone could you give me an example it'll be very useful. Thanks

Comment: Why not to use `DozerBeanMapperSingletonWrapper.getInstance()`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think something like this should work:

```
@Configuration
public class YourConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "org.dozer.Mapper")
  public DozerBeanMapper dozerBean() {
    List<String> mappingFiles = Arrays.asList(
      "dozer-global-configuration.xml", 
      "dozer-bean-mappings.xml",
      "more-dozer-bean-mappings.xml"
    );

    DozerBeanMapper dozerBean = new DozerBeanMapper();
    dozerBean.setMappingFiles(mappingFiles);
    return dozerBean;
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank your for your suggestions. It's what i am doing.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using `DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean` instead of `DozerBeanMapper` you may use something like this.

```
@Configuration
public class MappingConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean dozerBeanMapperFactoryBean(@Value("classpath*:mappings/*mappings.xml") Resource[] resources) throws Exception {
        final DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean dozerBeanMapperFactoryBean = new DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean();
        // Other configurations
        dozerBeanMapperFactoryBean.setMappingFiles(resources);
        return dozerBeanMapperFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

This way you can import your mappings automatically. Than simple inject your Mapper and use.

```
@Autowired
private Mapper mapper;
```

> **Update with Dozer 5.5.1**

In dozer 5.5.1, DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean is removed. So if you want to go with an updated version you need do something like below,

```
@Bean
public Mapper mapper(@Value(value = "classpath*:mappings/*mappings.xml") Resource[] resourceArray) throws IOException {
    List<String> mappingFileUrlList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Resource resource : resourceArray) {
        mappingFileUrlList.add(String.valueOf(resource.getURL()));
    }
    DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
    dozerBeanMapper.setMappingFiles(mappingFileUrlList);
    return dozerBeanMapper;
}
```

Now inject mapper as told above

```
@Autowired
private Mapper mapper;
```

And use like below example,

```
mapper.map(source_object, destination.class);
```

eg.
    mapper.map(admin, UserDTO.class);

Comment: Late to the party here, but I can't find org.dozer.spring package in the Dozer 5.5.1 release. Has DozerBeanMapperFactoryBean been replaced/moved?

Comment: @sMaN yes it removed in Dozer 5.5.1.

Comment: Can be improved slightly by using:     `new DozerBeanMapper(mappingFileUrlList)`

Answer (score 9):

Just in case someone wants to avoid xml dozer file. You can use a builder directly in java. For me it's the way to go in a annotation Spring context.

See more information at [mapping api dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/apimappings.html)

```
    @Bean
public DozerBeanMapper mapper() throws Exception {
    DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
    mapper.addMapping(objectMappingBuilder);
    return mapper;
}

BeanMappingBuilder objectMappingBuilder = new BeanMappingBuilder() {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        mapping(Bean1.class, Bean2.class)
                .fields("id", "id").fields("name", "name");
    }
};
```

In my case it was more efficient (At least the first time). Didn't do any benchmark or anything.

Comment: this is good but if u have 20 fields to map u will repeat this .fields("id", "id").fields("name", "name");
 20 times?

Comment: You could try to use annotation in your class http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/annotations.html

Comment: what I understood is we don't have to put annotation in all fields  private    Long id;

    private String name; in target class all fields will be mapped even though we have only one field mapped ? 

    @Mapping("binaryData")
    private String data;

Comment: I haven't tried but it's my understanding. You can exclude fields if it's what you need.